# incrementing variable after evaluation in C

Tags: c

code 1:

```
i = 0;
while ( arr[i++] != EOF )
     printf("%d", i);
```

output: 1 2 3 4

code 2:

```
i = 0;
while ( arr[i] != EOF )
{
      printf("%d", i);
      i++;
}
```

output: 0 1 2 3

In the above code, `arr[] = "//\n\0"`

However, I assume i++ should first assign i and increment right?

i.e.,

```
if i = 1
j = i++
j = 1 (Not 2)
```

So, what exactly is happening in code 1 and why it isn't behaving like code 2?

Comment: It's funny how the creator of the language doesn't know such a fundamental thing.

Comment: Might that be because when you are dead, your brain stops working? ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson that was evil :P

Comment: Sorry, for those not familiar with it, Dennis Ritchie is one of the two "inventors" of the C language. Brian Kernighan being the other. The inventor, Dennis died in 2011. Obviously, the author of this question is either Dennis talking from the other side (and just tricking us), or just happens to call himself that anyways (or its the real name of the user!) Sorry if that was a little bad taste...

Comment: I am the ghost.. Of course forgot all C after I died

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increment `i` when you do this `arr[i++]`, so when you go to print it out of course it will be incremented already.

Instead print out the array element so you know you got the right one:

```
i = 0;
char c;
while ( (c = arr[i++]) != EOF )
     printf("%c", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

...maybe I'm missing the point of your quetion but:

`So, what exactly is happening in code 1 and why it isn't behaving like code 2?`

Once you hit the `i++` it will increment and save that new value into `i`. So:

```
i = 0;                     // i = 0
while ( arr[i++] != EOF )  // i = 1, 2, etc now before the print
     printf("%d", i);      // the incremented i is printed

i = 0;                     // i = 0
while ( arr[i] != EOF )  
{
      printf("%d", i);     // i still = 0 and that's printed
      i++;                 // now i = 1, 2, etc
}
```

If you're asking about `i++` vs `++i` once the line that the increment (pre or post) is done on is executed, the new values is stored. So in your 1st case the increment is done during the while check, so it's saved at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in code you print `i` after incrementing it.

Immediately after the loop condition, `i` is incremented and becomes 1. By the time you print, `i` has already been incremented. That's why it prints differently when compared to code 2.